# Machine Learning, Imputing values that should be blank

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, data-imputation

Sometimes data sets contain variables that indicate the presence of an event and the value that represented the event.

As an example say a teacher wants to predict the grades of his students. Some of the students may have been in his class last year and he can use that grade as a variable. However maybe only 20% of the students were in his class so the rest of the 80% will have a Null value. Most ML algorithms cannot accept Null values so the variable would have to somehow be imputed.

I cannot think of an imputation method that would make sense here, the standard mean/mode would imply that all students were in the class and since the variable is pretty unbalance and 80% of the values would be imputed I don't imagine it would hold any valuable information.

Are there any methods to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that you are dealing with sparse data, however imputation is a difficult and often an attempt of imputation can add trivial amount of difference. You may look out on for [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103500/machine-learning-algorithms-to-handle-missing-data) link for some approaches like Gharamani and Jordan.
These are variants of SVM, focused with Sparse nature.

Answer (score 1):

Since last year's grade should be an important feature, we should use it whenever it is available.
I think that a stratified model should work here. Create 2 different models, one for last year students, the other for the remaining 80%. I think maybe there will be other features for the 20% sample, all the others will be in common for the 2 models.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of the notes, you could try to transform it by categories, where the null values will have a different category.

Another option would be to impute by the mean or the median, but previously it would create a binary variable to identify the null values.